# merging two lists, removing empty strings

Tags: python, list

I'm a bit new to python's data structure tricks, and I've been struggling with a simple problem.

I have 2 2d lists

```
L1=[[1, '', 3],[1, '', 3]...]
L2=[['',2,''],['',2,''].....]
```

I'm looking for a simple way to merge the two lists such that the result is a new 2d list in the form:

```
result=[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]....]
```

I've tried

```
newestlist=[sum(x,[]) for x in zip(mylist, mylist2)]
```

but it yields the result

```
badresult=[[1,'',3,'',2,'']....]
```

is there a way way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work if any numbers are 0:

```
>>> [[x or y or 0 for x, y in zip(a, b)] for a, b in zip(L1, L2)]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Edit: Breaking the comprehension into a for loop for clarity:

```
output = []
for a, b in zip(L1, L2):
    innerlist = []
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        innerlist.append(x or y or 0)  # 1 or '' = 1; '' or 2 = 2; etc
    output.append(innerlist)
```

Comment: This works beautifully.  I stumped as to why, but I guess that means more documentation for me...

Comment: @Mike, edited with a for loop for clarity. The comprehension does what's in the for loop

Comment: Thank you for this clarification!  So if I understand correctly, the x== our "content" item (1,2 or 3) and y==our "non-content" item ('')?

Comment: Not necessarily. x loops through `[1, '', 3]` and y loops through `['', 2, '']`. The `or` picks the one you want

Comment: `x or y or 0` is an easy fix for the zeros case.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
newestlist = [[a if a != "" else b for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]
              for l1, l2 in zip(L1, L2)]
```

This gives me your desired output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```